# Matplotlib: Removing all artists and lines

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

Let's say I make a series of AnnotationBbox'es in matplotlib through a for loop, like this:

```
 for city in cities:
     x, y = self.map(city[1], city[0])

     ab = AnnotationBbox(imagebox, [x,y],
                                xybox=(0, 0),
                                xycoords='data',
                                boxcoords="offset points",
                                frameon=False)
            self.axes.add_artist(ab)
            self.locationImages.append(ab)
```

In this example, I've created a series of AnnotationBBoxes, and stored them in a list called self.locationImages. Then I go through the self.locationImages in a loop, and remove each one by doing this:

```
    for image in self.locationImages:
        image.remove()
```

Is there a way to remove all the artists, without having to go through a loop? Or to remove all artists, and lines completely, without having to remove the axes or the figure?

I'm plotting points on a map, and I need the map to stay. I'm doing zoom ins and outs, but during zoom ins and outs, I need to remove everything and replot. I'm working with a large data set and doing iterations is an expensive action

Comment: using `set_visible` might be a better option than removing the artists. http://matplotlib.org/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.artist.Artist.set_visible  You will still have to trigger a re-draw, but you won't have to set up and tear down the artists.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a pretty nasty solution would be to do the following:

```py
# remove all artists
while ax.artists != []:
  ax.artists[0].remove()

#remove all lines
while ax.lines != []:
  ax.lines[0].remove()
```

This works for dynamic plots (e.g. animation or `ipywidgets`). But if you tell there has to be a better way -- I'd definitely agree :)

Answer (score -1):

From matplotlib's `pyplot` interface, you can `pyplot.cla()` to clear an entire axis and `pyplot.clf()` to clear an entire figure.

Comment: Those are `axes` and `figure` level functions as well-> `ax.cla()` and `fig.clf()`, but they will remove everything, including the map the OP wants to keep.

Comment: @tcaswell whoops. not sure how i missed that!